# Variable does not exist error - SOQL for loop

Tags: apex, soql, opportunity, map, loop

What could be the problem in below code. I am getting the error "Variable does not exist : Account"

```
    List<Opportunity> opp = [Select o.Id, o.AccountId, o.Account.Description from opportunity o where Id IN :optymap.keySet()] ; 
    
    for(List<Opportunity> oppfor : opp){
        
        If(oppfor.Account.Description = 'ABC'){
            
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable defined in the loop needs to be a single instance of Opportunity rather than another list of Opportunity:

```
List<Opportunity> opp = [Select o.Id, o.AccountId, o.Account.Description from opportunity o where Id IN :optymap.keySet()] ; 

for(Opportunity oppfor : opp){
    
    If(oppfor.Account.Description == 'ABC'){
        
}
```